# Accelerated through a potential difference

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, acceleration, potential, voltage

Say a electron is accelerated through a potential difference of 10v established between two points A and B 1metre distance apart.

Then would i only be able to say that a electron is accelerated through a potential difference of 10v if the electron travels through 1metre to gain 10joule of kinetic energy or or it will just gain 10joule of kinetic energy just by being in that electric field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A charged particle only gains energy by moving from one point to another at a different potential. If the electron doesn't move, then it doesn't gain any energy. So, the electron actually has to move from point A to point B to gain energy from the potential difference.

The following is a response to saying the electron gains "10 joules" of energy.

The kinetic energy gained by a charged particle when passing through a potential difference is equal to the charge of the particle multiplied by the potential difference.
$$K = qV$$
where $K$ is the kinetic energy, $q$ is the charge of the particle, and $V$ is the voltage difference. An electron would only gain 10 joules of kinetic energy if it had a charge of 1 Coulomb, which is a very large charge. The actual charge of an electron is about 1.602$\times$10$^{-19}$ C. So, an electron passing through a 10V potential difference ends up with 1.602$\times$10$^{-18}$ joules of kinetic energy.

Because these numbers are so small, a different unit of energy is often used. This unit is called the electron-volt (eV), which is equal to the energy gained by an electron when it passes through a 1-volt potential difference. One electron-volt is equal to 1.602$\times$10$^{-19}$ J. This makes calculations easier because, to use your problem as an example, an electron passing through a 10V potential difference gains 10 eV of energy.

Comment: I am completely satisfied but there one more thing i want to ask. If there is a electric circuit with a bulb and after i connect a battery to pass the electric current , it will suddenly glow. Lot of people tell that a current is set up instantly due to presence of eletrons all over in the metal wire but won't they have to move some distance to actually gain kinetic energy which then can be converted into heat energy to make the bulb glow(consider non led)? Then why the bulb suddenly glows up ?

Comment: @Cyberax Here's an analogy. Imagine a bunch of marbles all lined up in a single line. You shoot another marble at the first marble in the line. Each marble in the line hits the next marble in the line until the last marble shoots away. The marble you shot would have had a certain kinetic energy, but it hit the next marble instead. The last marble ends up with the kinetic energy, not the one you shot. [cont.]

Comment: @Cyberax Now, imagine that at the far end of the marble line is a nail stuck into a piece of wood. Now, when you shoot a marble at the near end of the line, the marbles collide with each other down the line until the last marble hits the nail, driving it into the wood. None of the marbles end up with any kinetic energy. All of the energy of the shot ends up as work driving the nail into the wood. [cont.]

Comment: @Cyberax Electricity is similar. The electron that exits a 9V battery would have 9eV of kinetic energy it it was traveling from one terminal to another in a vacuum. But, the electron enters a conductive wire instead. There, it collides with other electrons in the wire, push them instead of traveling with any speed. The electrons in the wire push other electrons farther down the wire until the light bulb. There, the energy from the battery goes into heating the wire instead of push electrons with the same force. [cont.]

Comment: @Cyberax Like the marbles driving the nail, the energy of the electrons coming out of the battery gets converted into heat and light instead of kinetic energy. Also like the marbles, the pushing travels down the line of marbles/electrons faster than any individual marble/electron.

Comment: Thanks your analogy works well. So should i assume that a electron starts up energy of 9ev , instead of converting it into kinetic energy it transfers it up through chain of electrons to the bulb which gets converted into heat.

Comment: @Cyberax Correct.

Comment: @Cyberax Since the moderators here don't like comments, I would suggest one of two actions. (1) Make your first comment into a new question where I'll copy my comments. (2) Copy these comments to a text file on your personal computer before the deletion occurs.

Comment: I have created another question

Answer (score 0):

The e has the potential energy 10eV, it gains kinetic energy if it moves. Same thing: a mass is at high 10m to some reference plain. it has potential energy of $mgh$ it gains kinetic energy only if it falls down. So you can not say it "gains energy only by moving, it just changes the form of energy.